# Python - intersection between a list and keys of a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this:

```
l1 = ['200:200', '90:728']
```

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
d1 = {'200:200':{'foo':'bar'},'300:300':{'foo':'bar'}}
```

I need to get filter out the dictioary where only the keys are in l1.  The dict should look like this:

```
result = {'200:200':{'foo':'bar'}}
```

In essence a intersection of a list and the keys of a dict while returning the subsection of the dict.

How do I do this efficiently where time is an issue for a large sets?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
keys = set(l1).intersection(set(d1.keys()))
result = {k:d1[k] for k in keys}
```

**EDIT:** As commenters suggest you can replace the first line with, in Python 2.x:

```
keys = set(l1).intersection(d1)
```

And in Python 3.x:

```
keys = d1.keys() & l1
```

Comment: Note that in 3.x, a dictionary view is set-like, so you don't need to wrap it in `set()`. In fact, in 3.x, the entire top line can be `keys = d1.keys() & l1`.

Comment: @Lattyware you don't need to cast it into a set in 2.x either

Comment: Don't even need keys(), `set(l1).intersection(d1)`

Comment: And not wrapping d1.keys() has the advantage that if d1 is large you won't be O(len(d1)).

Comment: In 3.x, the `keys()` call doesn't cost anything, it's worth noting - as it just makes a `dict` view. I've shown in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

In 3.x, this can be as simple as:

```
>>> {k: d1[k] for k in (d1.keys() & l1)}
{'200:200': {'foo': 'bar'}}
```

Under 2.7, you can use `dict.viewkeys()` to recreate this functionality:

```
>>> {k: d1[k] for k in (d1.viewkeys() & l1)}
{'200:200': {'foo': 'bar'}}
```

Under older versions of 2.x, it's a tad more verbose:

```
>>> {k: d1[k] for k in (set(d1).intersection(l1))}
{'200:200': {'foo': 'bar'}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about each solution performance, but I would do:

```
{k: v for k, v in d1.items() if k in l1}
```

Comment: This will work even when a member of l1 is not a key in d1, which many others will fail on.

Comment: This may be more performant than the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11157736/3217306) as it seems the dictionary lookup (`d1[k]`) in that answer may be a bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension in the dict constructor:

```
result = dict([(k,d1[k]) for k in l1 if k in d1])
```

If you're worried about removing duplicate keys, make l1 into a set first:

```
result = dict([(k,d1[k]) for k in set(l1) if k in d1])
```

Comment: Also note you can do dict generator expressions as in my solution. So `{k:v for k,v in arr}`. This even has the benefit of dealing with duplicates.

Comment: @JPvdMerwe It's a dict comprehension, not a dict generator expression - generator expressions are lazy, a dict comprehension is not.

Comment: @Lattyware: I knew I should have checked the docs to get my terminology right. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Define efficient. Anyway here's what I would do. If it was too slow I'd probably move it to Cython.

```
s1 = set(l1)
s2 = set(d1.keys())
s3 = s1 & s2
# now you can access d1 using only keys in s3, or construct a new dict if you like
d2 = dict([(k,d1[k]) for k in s3])
```

Answer (score 0):

If memory allocation and deallocation is making this process take too long, itertools to the rescue.

```
import itertools
result = {dict_key:d1[dict_key] for dict_key in itertools.ifilter(lambda list_item: list_item in d1, l1) }
```

This doesn't unnecessarily allocate memory for a whole new collection, and l1 could easily be an iterator instead of a list.