# How to create small dict from another dict with array of keys?

Tags: python

I have a simple dictionary `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4 }` and list of keys: `['a', 'd']`.

What is the better way to construct dict object containing only keys from the list: `{'a': 1, 'd': 4}`?

Comment: And what's your way of doing it?

Comment: This was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157704/python-intersection-between-a-list-and-keys-of-a-dictionary

Comment: I'm new to python, simple "for" loop, but it looks awful:

    d={'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4 }
    l=['a','d']
    r={}
    for key in l:
        r[key]=d[key]

Comment: also new to the stackoverflow, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4 }
l = ['a', 'd']

new_d = {k:d[k] for k in l}
```

`new_d` is now `{'a': 1, 'd': 4}`

Comment: nice answer, [here is a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/python-create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension?answertab=votes#tab-top) using `dict()` how to use for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
c = ['a', 'b']
new_d = {}

for key in c:
    new_d[key]= d[key]
```