# Why can I check if a list contains keys to a dictionary using bitwise AND?

Tags: python, dictionary, bit-manipulation

I happened to stumble across this question [Python - intersection between a list and keys of a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157704/python-intersection-between-a-list-and-keys-of-a-dictionary) , and unfortunately did not have the required reputation to ask:

Why does this work?

```
d1 = {'200:200':{'foo':'bar'},'300:300':{'foo':'bar'}}
l1 = ['200:200', '90:728']
keys = d1.keys() & l1
```

Comment: What, anyway, are you actually trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: i'm not the OP, but my guess is he wants to achieve some insight.

Comment: The code is copied from the link I gave, I was just curious as to how a bitwise operator allows an intersection to be found between an iterator and a set. However, it has now occured to me, that perhaps the & in this case is not a bitwise operator but overloaded to mean set intersection –

Answer (score 2):

It works because you are using Python 3. `d1.keys()` returns a list (Python 2) or an object of type `<class dict_keys>`. (Python 3), and `l1` is a list. In the Python 2 case the final statement gives `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'`. In Python 3 the `dict_keys` object is an iterable view, which apparently does have some sort of implementation of the `__and__()` method used to implement the `&` operation.

Comment: it looks like you misread the question, the OP asked "why does this work?", notice no "not".

Comment: I was going to delete this, but apparently some people found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

The result of `d1.keys()` is a set like view.

> Keys views are set-like since their entries are unique and hashable. If all values are hashable, so that (key, value) pairs are unique and hashable, then the items view is also set-like. (Values views are not treated as set-like since the entries are generally not unique.) For set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base class collections.abc.Set are available (for example, ==, <, or ^).

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

The second argument to `&` is only required to be an iterable of hashable objects (although this is not stated in the documentation).

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection

Answer (score 1):

it works in python3 (3.4.3 at least) because `dict#keys` returns and instance of `dict_keys`, which apparently implements (parts of?) the `set` interface.  and the `set` type has implementations of some infix integer operators with different (but similar) meanings.