# Python - intersection between list and dict keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, intersection

I have this list:

```
list1 = [{'Hello'}, {'Welcome'}, {'BYE'}]
```

And I have a dictionary:

```
dict1 = {'Welcome': 5, 'BYE': 3, 'How are you': 3}
```

I would like the result to be something like:

```
dict2 = {'Welcome': 5, 'BYE': 3}
```

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157704/python-intersection-between-a-list-and-keys-of-a-dictionary).
I tried:

```
dict2 = {k: dict1[k] for k in (dict1.keys() & list1)}
```

But it says:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Do I need first to make list1, like this:

```
list1 = ['Hello', 'Welcome', 'BYE']
```

And if this is the problem, then how?

Comment: Why is `list1` a list of sets with one item each? I suppose that could easily by simplified…?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a set of value from the `list1`:

```py
list1 = [{"Hello"}, {"Welcome"}, {"BYE"}]
dict1 = {"Welcome": 5, "BYE": 3, "How are you": 3}


dict2 = {k: dict1[k] for k in (dict1.keys() & {v for s in list1 for v in s})}
print(dict2)
```

Prints:

```py
{'BYE': 3, 'Welcome': 5}
```

Comment: You could also use set.union to "join" all the sets from the list before intersecting with the dict keys: `dict1.keys() & set.union(*list1)`. if `list1` may be empty then you need `set().union(...)`, as `set.union` needs at least a `self`.

Comment: @Masklinn i didn’t fully get this,  if list1 may be empty it is better to use union()? or what? can you please explain it, thank you.

Comment: The difference is in the subject: `set()` versus `set`. `set().union` is a *bound method* meaning its subject ("self") is bound to the empty set. `set.union` however is just a function (formerly "unbound method"), meaning it expects to be provided a `self` as first argument, this is not optional. This means `set.union(*list1)`, if called with an empty list, will raise a TypeError as a required parameter will be missing. `set().union(*list1)` should be slightly less efficient (as it always creates and passes an empty set) but works fine for empty lists.

Answer (score 1):

If you are required to start with that weird single-item-set-in-list list, I'd flatten it with `itertools.chain.from_iterable` into a simple list. From there, with a simple dictionary comprehension, you create a new dictionary for each key from `list1` that exists in `dict1`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list1 = [{'Hello'}, {'Welcome'}, {'BYE'}]
>>> dict1 = {'Welcome': 5, 'BYE': 3, 'How are you': 3}
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(list1))
['Hello', 'Welcome', 'BYE']
>>> {k: dict1[k] for k in chain.from_iterable(list1) if k in dict1}
{'Welcome': 5, 'BYE': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes your variable list1 is a list of set, you might do this:

```
dict2 = {k: dict1[k] for k in set(dict1.keys()).intersection(set().union(*list1))}
```